# Twitter streaming using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, twitter, streaming

I'm trying to stream twitter data using spark scala code.I'm able to fetch data and create a dataframe and view it.But when trying to extract status.getPlace.getCountry() I get a java.lang.NullPointerException.

Spark version: 2.0.0,
Scala version: 2.11.8

Tried with if conditions,checking value etc,but in vain.

Code:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Twitter Spark Example").getOrCreate()
val ssc = new StreamingContext(spark.sparkContext,Seconds(5))

val filters:Seq[String] =  Seq("hadoop")
val cb = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .setOAuthConsumerKey("******")
      .setOAuthConsumerSecret("******")
      .setOAuthAccessToken("********")
      .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("******").build()

val twitter_auth = new TwitterFactory(cb)
val a = new OAuthAuthorization(cb)
val atwitter:Option[twitter4j.auth.Authorization] =  Some(twitter_auth.getInstance(a).getAuthorization())

val tweetsdstream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, atwitter, filters, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2)
val data = tweetsdstream.map {status => 
      val places = status.getPlace
      val id = status.getUser.getId
      val date = status.getUser.getCreatedAt.toString()
      val user = status.getUser.getName()
      val place = places.getCountry()

      (id,date,user,place)
      }
data.foreachRDD{rdd =>
      import spark.implicits._
      rdd.toDF("id","date","user","place").show()
    }

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Is there any restriction on accessing location information from twitter?
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Actually most of the time `getPlace` and `getCountry` contains the null value you can try using geoLocation instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Option` to deal with `null`s:

```
val data = tweetsdstream.map {
  status =>
    val place = Option(status.getPlace).map(_.getCountry).orNull
    val id = status.getUser.getId
    val user = status.getUser.getName
    val date = status.getUser.getCreatedAt.toString
    (id, date, user, place)
}
```

This way, you'll be able to visualize all tweets, regardless if they have a country or not (and it will be null where the country is not defined).

`Option` is very useful to handle possibly missing data, feel free to use it for other possibly empty fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think please change at line `*val tweetsdstream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, atwitter, filters, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2)*`

Change into like this then simply workout it

```
val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(scc, None, filters)

val hashTags = stream.flatMap(status => status.getText.split(" ").filter(_.startsWith("#")))
```

If you want more info go through: http://commandstech.com/spark-streaming-twitter-example/